# Upload an image in jquery without any api

Tags: php, jquery, image, file-upload, upload

i want to upload an image to folder and return the name of the image(name of the image should be a random number) on a click of a div i searched a lot but not get any fit result

```
<div id="click">

  <img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/avatar.png');?>">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want a image name should be random number, every time ?

Comment: yes so there will be no same name problem right @MohitTanwani

Comment: that can be done on php side

Comment: Please provide me your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but I will try to answer you. You can not do that with pure jQuery. Remember that jQuery is client side, unless you have an API or a server side app running waiting for jQuery to send an image you will not be able to save it.

Remember, file name is given at the moment of saving it in a folder on server.

After server has saved the image(s) you can return the name, so jQuery can grab it and work with it.

Hope it helps